# Is it possible to rename MySQL’s own database from "mysql" to something else?

Tags: mysql

Upon installation MySQL creates and uses the database named "mysql" for storing users, privileges etc. Can this database be renamed to something else? Or in other words, can we force mysqld to use a database other than "mysql" for its internal use?

Thanks

Comment: In which case it won't use the replicated database anymore?

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: It should be using its own system database for users etc and not master's "mysql" database. The "mysql" DB from master and other replicated databases should still be available to slave's mysqld.

Comment: @DavidPostill My question is not about any problem actually. I just wanted to know whether its possible with MySQL or not. I couldn't find a way to achieve that by googling and reading MySQL docs so felt like asking the experienced DB admins here.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have reworded the question for more clarity.

Comment: It seems to be that you have changed the scope and meaning of the question.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, its possible.

I've just renamed it on a dev box of mine and the rename worked - however, I started getting a lot of errors almost immediately and routing procedures running on background threads started erroring straight away.

I'm sure if you had the time to edit all of these procedures and correct them (and then  maintain them through updates and upgrades) that its possible - but its just not worth the effort.